# How to create a popup window with allow and deny options in Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I want to create a popup window in Javascript with two options 'Allow' or 'Deny'. Then I want to collect information from the option chosen and take particular action.

`if (allow) { do foo }  else { do bar }`

How to code a popup from whose mouseclick, the value of allow or deny buttons can be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Simple..

```
function myFunction() {
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r == true) {
            alert("take as yes");
        } else {
           alert("take as no");
        }
```

demo :[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxjy4ae6/52/)